# SQL return multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, grouping

I am using PHP and MySQL
Let's say i have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE smth=?
```

And i need to perform 10 of this queries on the same table, each with different 'smth' value.
Can i make SQL return multiple tables in one run, each for it's 'smth' value?

Comment: Hi @Agr, you want to return multiple tables or multiple values ?

Comment: Pleasure provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @VBokšić i want to return multiple tables, as if i queried 10 times.

Comment: And you are looking for something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdf4526c02f059b0f6fa381733b82c04

Comment: @VBokšić yes, like this. But not only for rows, but for whole tables, like
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE smth=1"
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE smth=2"

"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE smth in (1,2)"
to return two tables, first with results for query 1 and second with returlts for query 2

Comment: Agr, I believe that your description is very bad in your question and I believe you should mark the answer from @GordonLinoff as correct  and open new question where you will enter more details and in that details please do not forget to put tag MySQL and try to describe the situation as best as possible as well try to add some examples. Why do I say this is because for the description you have given that answer below from Gordon is correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE smth IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

You can pass all ten values in as parameters.

Comment: But with this approach i have to manually sort and group results, that's not what i am looking for.